# Linking json to javascript to form a graph

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I want to display a graph based on data from a database. I am using PHP and Javascript for retrieving all the data and then form a graph. Here is my code for convert my data in from of jason format.

```
$totalrow = mysqli_num_rows($result_set);
$json='[{';
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set)) {
$i++;
if($i==1) {
    $json.= '"name": "datetime", "data": ["'.$row['datetime'].'"';
}

else if($i==$totalrow) {
    $json.= ']}';
}

else {
    $json.= ',"'.$row['datetime'].'"';
}
}

$json.=', {';
$i = 0;
$result_set2 =  mysqli_query($conn, $SQLSELECT);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set2)) {
$i++;
if($i==1) {
    $json.= '"name": "PV_Value", "data": ['.$row['PV_Value'];
}

else if($i==$totalrow) {
    $json.= ']}';
}

else {
    $json.= ','.$row['PV_Value'];
}
 }
 $json.= ']';
?>
```

and here is my javascript that used to display line graph based on my data in the database:

```
$(function () {
$.getJSON('$json', function (data) {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature of PV Value for Process Control'
        },
         subtitle: {
            text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                    'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch  
        the chart to zoom in'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
                    alert("Min: "+e.min+"\n"
                            +"Max: "+e.max);
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'PV Value'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: {
                        x1: 0,
                        y1: 0,
                        x2: 0,
                        y2: 1
                    },
                    stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                        [1, 

     Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                marker: {
                    radius: 2
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: data
           }]
        });
    });
});
```

The problem was my first line sign($) on javascript is not define.

```
$(function () {
```

Please help me in indentyfing the error

Comment: Have you included jquery?

Comment: Also, I'm guessing this `$.getJSON('$json'` should be this `$.getJSON('<?php echo $json?>'`

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I see the following shortcomings in your code:

1. The undefined `$` error might be because you haven't included jquery lib.
2. Also, I'm guessing this `$.getJSON('$json'` should be this `$.getJSON('<?php echo $json?>'`
3. Thirdly, the way you created json in php isn't exactly efficient. You should use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).
4. This `document.ontouchstart === undefined` should be this `document.ontouchstart === 'undefined'`.